# Django changes image name before uploading to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django-1.7` and have a field of type `ImageField` in a model to store the image link to the AWS S3 bucket

```
cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='s3_bucket_name/', null=True, blank=True)
```

In the `settins.py` file, I have

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'url_to_aws_s3_bucket'
MEDIA_URL = 'url_to_aws_s3_bucket'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 's3_access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 's3_secret_key'
```

**The problem is when I upload an image with `@` character in its name, Django removes all instances of `@` before uploading the image to Amazon S3 bucket.**

How do I keep the name of the image file intact?

Comment: do you have a store method for S3 bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a string as `upload_to='s3_bucket_name/'`, I passed the function

```
def change_filename(instance, filename):
    return 'bucket_name/' + filename

# inside the model class
cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=change_filename, null=True, blank=True)
```

and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inherit from S3BotoStorage and redefine get_available_name method:

```
class MyS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

Comment: I tried it. It still does the same - removes all `@`s before uploading the image file.